# removing non-fixed number of lines from the beginning of file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file like the small example:

small example:

```
ScannerID,1609P0139
StagePosition,1
BindingDensity,0.19
CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,196
Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,962
Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,390
Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,67
```

I would like to remove the 1st few lines until this line (header line):

```
CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
```

in this example there are 3 lines before the header line but it might be different every time. here is the expected output:

```
CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,196
Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,962
Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,390
Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,67
```

I wrote the following code for that:

```
with open("infile.csv" , "r") as inf,
    for line in inf:
        if line.startswith("CodeClass"):
            with open('fileName.csv', 'w') as f:
                for line in s:
                    f.write(line)
```

but it does not return what I am looking for. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: you want to write another csv files of you expected output, right?

Comment: what is `s` in your code? Also please post exactly what it **does** return

Answer (score 0):

Since looping on a file "remembers" your last position you could do something like this:

```py
with open("infile.csv" , "r") as inf, open('fileName.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in inf:
        if line.startswith("CodeClass"):
            f.write(line)
            break
    for line in inf:
        f.write(line)
```

---

Apart from that you should consider working with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) which is perfect for working with tabular data/CSV files.

Comment: how can I do that in pandas

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

```
result = []
useval = False
with open('infile.csv', "rU") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("CodeClass"):
            useval = True

        if useval:
            result.append(line)

with open('fileName.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in result:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This are the data now in `infile.csv`

```sh
ScannerID,1609P0139
StagePosition,1
BindingDensity,0.19
CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,196
Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,962
Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,390
Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,67
```

Try this code,

```py
import csv

status = False
datas = []

with open('infile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[0] == 'CodeClass':
            status = True

        if status:
            datas.append(row)


with open('fileName.csv', 'w') as file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for data in datas:
        employee_writer.writerow(data)
```

After that you'll receive `fileName.csv` with following values.

```sh
CodeClass,Name,Accession,Count
Endogenous,CCNO,NM_021147.4,196
Endogenous,MYC,NM_002467.3,962
Endogenous,CD79A,NM_001783.3,390
Endogenous,FSTL3,NM_005860.2,67
```